# Change comment style in web-mode

Tags: web-mode

I am using web-mode 20161003.1327

At the moment when I comment  a region in web-mode, it comments like this;

```
/* import chai from 'chai';
 * import 'babel-polyfill';
 * import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
 * import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 * import * as ActionTypes from '../actions/ForecastActions';
 * 
 * const expect = chai.expect;
 * 
 * const middlewares = [ thunk ];
 * const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
 * 
 * /
```

This is not good for uncommenting only a section.

Can I change the commenting to use double forward slash?

I've tried using `(setq web-mode-comment-style 2)` but this appears to do nothing.

I have also tried `web-mode-comment-formats` but it also does not appear to work:

```
(require 'web-mode)

(add-to-list 'web-mode-comment-formats '("javascript" . "//"))

(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "web-mode settings"
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js?$" . web-mode))
```

Comment: Take a look at `web-mode-comment-formats`. I think this is the proper variable for what you want.

Comment: @caisah I've tried that also but it does not appear to do anything.  I've updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`web-mode-comment-formats` is a buffer local variable.  Also, `add-to-list` may not work correctly, since there is already a mapping for `javascript` to `/*`.

You can try one of the following:

```el
(setq-default web-mode-comment-formats
              (remove '("javascript" . "/*")
                      web-mode-comment-formats))
(add-to-list 'web-mode-comment-formats '("javascript" . "//"))
```

Or

```el
(setq-default web-mode-comment-formats
              '(("java"       . "/*")
                ("javascript" . "//")
                ("php"        . "/*")))
```

Comment: Only the second solution works for me, because `web-mode-comment-formats` is undefined when my `.emacs` file loads. I wonder why `web-mode-comment-formats` is undefined, and where can I add this code to manipulate this variable, as you are doing in the first solution?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have it set as: `web-mode-comment-formats is a variable defined in ‘web-mode.el’.
Its value is (("jsx" . "//") ("javascript" . "//"))`